# Android Search Market on Keyword URL?

Tags: android, google-play

To Launch the market I usually do this:

Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.package.package2.package3"));
startActivity(intent);

But I would like to run a search based on a keyword like "Happy Toasters"

What is the URL for that kind of search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=your keewords here"));
startActivity(intent);
```